# Kubectl command throws error when executed from python script but manual execution works fine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeconfig

I'm trying to execute `kubectl` commands in python

```py
process = subprocess.run(["kubectl", "get", "pods", "-n", "argocd"])
```

which throws error:

```
__main__ - INFO - 
E0328 08:18:04.126243   25976 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0328 08:18:04.126801   25976 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0328 08:18:04.129854   25976 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0328 08:18:04.130344   25976 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0328 08:18:04.131804   25976 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
__main__ - ERROR - Failed to get po.
NoneType: None
```

But when I execute the same command manually from the master node I see output without any issues.

Can someone help me figure out what's the issue here?

Comment: Are you running your Python script in the same place that you are successfully running `kubectl` on the command line? The error you are seeing suggests that when run from your Python script, `kubectl` is not able to find its configuration file.

Comment: Also consider using a [Kubernetes client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) rather than shelling out to `kubectl`.  (Though this will have the same issue with finding the Kubernetes configuration that @larsks describes.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this issue is related to authentication with the KubeAPI server. To troubleshoot and resolve this problem follow these steps:

**Check Kubernetes API Server Configuration:**

Ensure that your Python environment has access to the Kubernetes configuration file (~/.kube/config by default). This file contains the credentials and configuration details required to access the Kubernetes cluster.

**Verify Correct Context:**

Check if the Kubernetes configuration file specifies the correct context with the necessary permissions to list pods in the argocd namespace.

You can do this by running:

```
kubectl config current-context
```

**Test API Server Reachability:**

Verify that the Kubernetes API server is reachable from your Python environment using:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api
```

Replace `localhost:8080` with the actual API server address if different, you can check your api server port by running `cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

**Add Authentication:**

If authentication is required by your Kubernetes API server and is not configured in your Python environment, set up authentication. This can involve using service account tokens, kubeconfig files with credentials, or other authentication methods based on your Kubernetes cluster setup.

**Debugging Output:**

Include more verbose output in your Python script to capture any error messages or details that might help diagnose the authentication issue.

Example:

```
import subprocess

try:
    result = subprocess.run(["kubectl", "get", "pods", "-n", "argocd"], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
    print("Output:", result.stdout)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
    print("Error Output:", e.stderr)
```